# how to set Image for UIBarButton item in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, uibarbuttonitem

I have tab bar button in item named login I want to assign the custom image for this any idea how it is possible?

I am doing following way but app crashes.

Here is the code:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(loginPressed)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loginN.png"] f
```

Comment: drag my code as it is where you want...

Comment: your question looks confusing. you mentioned UIBarbutton item in your question but in your description and tags you mentioned UITabbarItem. What you are using actually ?

Answer (score 1):

Try it in this way:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.png"];
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
[btn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(loginPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
UIBarButtonItem *rbBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rbBtn;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.png"];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [someButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(facebookshare)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

    UIBarButtonItem * rightbtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:someButton];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=rightbtn;
```

this might be helpful to you...